# Wood laminate floor wont snap together can I just nail it down

Tags: wood, installation, laminate

I bought a whole lot of this snap together wood flooring, thinking I would just snap it together and be done. The store was closing out all different styles and colors.
I was going to just mix and match. they are all the same height but the lips don't all match up so I can't get them to snap together. 
Can I use it as wood flooring, just cut the lip off and butt the sides together and nail or screw it down. I guess I could even just use liquid nails. I just need to get it done.

Comment: Is it wood or laminate?  I am not sure I have ever seen laminated wood.

Comment: Okay, your right. I think it's actually wood but it snaps together, I think they call it a floating floor. You have to put down this thin layer of plastic. I was going to put it down on top of my old 80's vinyl floor. It's just a single wide mobile home I'm trying to kinda upgrade. The sub floor is press board and the vinyl is glued and I just thought Maybe a quick fix would be to nail down the wood snap flooring after taking the tabs off the edges. ??? Maybe it could work, temp???

Comment: Engineered wood flooring.  You can do whatever you want with it if you allow some sort of room for expansion.  Also engineered flooring doesn't snap together.  It has a tongue and a groove and can be hammered into the next piece.  You will need to shave all the tongues off to use in this way, you will have to nail them down with 1/32 spacers.  It sounds more like a bad craft project than a floor install.  Also the wood will be at different heights which is really odd and could lead to scraped feet.

Comment: Okay, I will try one more time to hammer them together, I was told if I use a mallet and a small section of one piece of the wood it will work best that way. If I do decide to space it apart and just nail it down and  if I use all the same wood and nails that are spiral for tack strip installation will that help them stay in place or should I just use deck screws?

Comment: You can use whatever you want.  Take pictures for us.  This sounds like a complete disaster but who knows.  You are beyond trying to do something right at this point.

Comment: Okay wish me the best and yes I will send photos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more specific brand information my definitive answer is likely not. The reason being that most prefinished lock together flooring is designed to float. By float it should be able to expand and contract independent of the base layer or sub floor. Since you have at least two different types it is likely they will expand and contract at different rates. This may result in buckles in the floor or splits.